# Creation of timeseries depending on value of vector of df1 with timeseries of column of xts2 in R

Tags: r

I've got two datasets. I want to create a list of new timeseries depending on different character given in df1$col5. Therefore I have another xts 2 , which columnname (header) fits to the character of df1$col5. Each column of xts 2 includes a timeseries. The name of each ts for the list is given in df1/col1. In Addition to that I have to edit each new timeseries with a value from df1/col3.

It sounds rather chaotic, but it's the best way to discribe my problem.

How do I match a character of df1/col5 with one header of xts2?

I have searched quite a while but didn't find any solution.

df1 Looks like this:

```
        MKZ Elbekilometer MNW91-2010       Fix   Pegel Distanz_Pegel_m
1  43420072         178.2      70.70  70.37300  Torgau      18816.2011
2  43435074         172.0      72.09  71.81900  Torgau      11926.9932
3  43435084         177.0      70.93  70.61100  Torgau      15620.9210
4  43435086         171.8      72.14  71.87100  Torgau      11478.2310
5  44425470         172.2      72.05  71.76767  Torgau      17400.7983
6  44425476         172.2      72.05  71.76767  Torgau      14448.9073
7  45426142         154.0      75.91  75.72300  Torgau      21065.9449
8  45440655         125.4      84.18  83.94567   Riesa      17019.6066
9  46431146         117.0      87.17  87.04500   Riesa      23594.2523
10 46440130         116.0      87.45  87.32600   Riesa      10471.5078
```

MKZ shall be the name of each new timeseries in my list. The dependig character is given in Pegel, which fits to the columnname of xts2 which Looks like this:

```
            Schöna   Pirna Dresden  Meißen  Riesa Torgau
1980-01-01 119.583 110.576 105.742  98.522 92.036 79.038
1980-01-02 119.523 111.426 105.652  98.412 91.926 78.908
1980-01-03 119.413 111.316 105.592  98.362 91.876 78.848
1980-01-04 119.123 111.126 105.382  98.222 91.756 78.748
1980-01-05 119.103 110.956 105.282  98.032 91.536 78.488
1980-01-06 118.823 110.786 105.062  97.802 91.396 78.348
1980-01-07 118.783 110.726 104.972  97.722 91.276 78.128
1980-01-08 118.923 110.866 105.102  97.852 91.336 78.088
```

In the end it shall look like this:

```
data<-list()

data[[1]]
file[1] <- 43420072
```

```
           Torgau   newcol
1980-01-01  79.038  79.038+df1/col3
1980-01-02  78.908  78.908+df1/col3
1980-01-03  78.848  78.848+df1/col3
1980-01-04  78.748  78.748+df1/col3
1980-01-05  78.488  78.488+df1/col3
1980-01-06  78.348  78.348+df1/col3
1980-01-07  78.128  78.128+df1/col3
1980-01-08  78.088  78.088+df1/col3
```

**UPDATE**

Basically the answer works fine exept for all timeseries based on Pegel Schöna.
My Code Looks like this now:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

pegeluntereinander <- Pegelganglinien %>% 
  rownames_to_column('date') %>% 
  gather('Pegel','value', -date)

zus <- pegeluntereinander %>%
  left_join(Werte) %>% #WITHOUT running df1 %>% filter(MKZ == 43420072)
  select(date, Pegel, value, MKZ, `MNW91.2010`) %>% #Added MKZ as column for clarity
  mutate(new.col = value + `MNW91.2010`)

files<-Werte$MKZ
workspace<-...
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  filename<-Werte[i,][1,1]
  zeilen<-which(zus$MKZ==filename)
  mkz<-new.df[zeilen, ]
  filename<-as.character(filename)
  dateinamen_csv=paste(filename, "csv", sep = ".")
  speicherpfad_inkl_namen=paste(workspace,dateinamen_csv, sep = "/")
  write.csv(mkz, file = speicherpfad_inkl_namen, row.names = F)
}
```

to undestand the names of the dataframe:

```
Werte=df1
Pegelganglinien=df2
pegeluntereinander=df2.new
zus=df.new
```

Comment: What is meant by `+df1/col3`? For the new time series *43420072* do you want always subtract (OR add?) 70.70 from df1$MNW91-2010 (mean low water 1991 to 2010) from xts2$Torgau in a new column?

Comment: +df1/col3 is only an example showing that I'll work with the data later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Load your data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '        MKZ Elbekilometer MNW91-2010       Fix   Pegel Distanz_Pegel_m
1  43420072         178.2      70.70  70.37300  Torgau      18816.2011
2  43435074         172.0      72.09  71.81900  Torgau      11926.9932
3  43435084         177.0      70.93  70.61100  Torgau      15620.9210
4  43435086         171.8      72.14  71.87100  Torgau      11478.2310
5  44425470         172.2      72.05  71.76767  Torgau      17400.7983
6  44425476         172.2      72.05  71.76767  Torgau      14448.9073
7  45426142         154.0      75.91  75.72300  Torgau      21065.9449
8  45440655         125.4      84.18  83.94567   Riesa      17019.6066
9  46431146         117.0      87.17  87.04500   Riesa      23594.2523
10 46440130         116.0      87.45  87.32600   Riesa      10471.5078')

df2 <- read.table(text = '            Schöna   Pirna Dresden  Meißen  Riesa Torgau
  1980-01-01 119.583 110.576 105.742  98.522 92.036 79.038
1980-01-02 119.523 111.426 105.652  98.412 91.926 78.908
1980-01-03 119.413 111.316 105.592  98.362 91.876 78.848
1980-01-04 119.123 111.126 105.382  98.222 91.756 78.748
1980-01-05 119.103 110.956 105.282  98.032 91.536 78.488
1980-01-06 118.823 110.786 105.062  97.802 91.396 78.348
1980-01-07 118.783 110.726 104.972  97.722 91.276 78.128
1980-01-08 118.923 110.866 105.102  97.852 91.336 78.088')
```

We first format the second dataframe such that we can easily join it using `left_join` from dplyr. Then we filter the first dataframe on the MKZ you gave (`43420072`) and combine the data:

**2. Format the second dataframe (`df2`) such that we can easily join it**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

df2.new <- df2 %>% 
rownames_to_column('date') %>% 
gather('Pegel','value', -date)
```

**3. Build the new dataframe**

```
# We pick the correct data from the first dataframe
df1 <- df1 %>% filter(MKZ == 43420072)

# Build the new df
new.df <- df2.new %>%
  left_join(df1) %>%
  select(date, Pegel, value, `MNW91.2010`) %>%
  mutate(new.col = value + `MNW91.2010`)
```

**Output** 
This new dataframe will look how you described (filtered for Plegel == Torgau):

```
       date  Pegel  value MNW91.2010 new.col
1 1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038       70.7 149.738
2 1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908       70.7 149.608
3 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848       70.7 149.548
4 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748       70.7 149.448
5 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488       70.7 149.188
6 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348       70.7 149.048
7 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128       70.7 148.828
8 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088       70.7 148.788
```

---

**EDIT** 
Output without filtering for MKZ

```
new.df <- df2.new %>%
  left_join(df1) %>% #WITHOUT running df1 %>% filter(MKZ == 43420072)
  select(date, Pegel, value, MKZ, `MNW91.2010`) %>% #Added MKZ as column for clarity
  mutate(new.col = value + `MNW91.2010`)
```

This produces the following data frame for `Torgau`:

```
         date  Pegel  value      MKZ MNW91.2010 new.col
1  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 43420072      70.70 149.738
2  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 43435074      72.09 151.128
3  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 43435084      70.93 149.968
4  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 43435086      72.14 151.178
5  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 44425470      72.05 151.088
6  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 44425476      72.05 151.088
7  1980-01-01 Torgau 79.038 45426142      75.91 154.948
8  1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 43420072      70.70 149.608
9  1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 43435074      72.09 150.998
10 1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 43435084      70.93 149.838
11 1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 43435086      72.14 151.048
12 1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 44425470      72.05 150.958
13 1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 44425476      72.05 150.958
14 1980-01-02 Torgau 78.908 45426142      75.91 154.818
15 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 43420072      70.70 149.548
16 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 43435074      72.09 150.938
17 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 43435084      70.93 149.778
18 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 43435086      72.14 150.988
19 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 44425470      72.05 150.898
20 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 44425476      72.05 150.898
21 1980-01-03 Torgau 78.848 45426142      75.91 154.758
22 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 43420072      70.70 149.448
23 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 43435074      72.09 150.838
24 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 43435084      70.93 149.678
25 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 43435086      72.14 150.888
26 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 44425470      72.05 150.798
27 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 44425476      72.05 150.798
28 1980-01-04 Torgau 78.748 45426142      75.91 154.658
29 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 43420072      70.70 149.188
30 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 43435074      72.09 150.578
31 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 43435084      70.93 149.418
32 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 43435086      72.14 150.628
33 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 44425470      72.05 150.538
34 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 44425476      72.05 150.538
35 1980-01-05 Torgau 78.488 45426142      75.91 154.398
36 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 43420072      70.70 149.048
37 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 43435074      72.09 150.438
38 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 43435084      70.93 149.278
39 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 43435086      72.14 150.488
40 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 44425470      72.05 150.398
41 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 44425476      72.05 150.398
42 1980-01-06 Torgau 78.348 45426142      75.91 154.258
43 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 43420072      70.70 148.828
44 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 43435074      72.09 150.218
45 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 43435084      70.93 149.058
46 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 43435086      72.14 150.268
47 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 44425470      72.05 150.178
48 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 44425476      72.05 150.178
49 1980-01-07 Torgau 78.128 45426142      75.91 154.038
50 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 43420072      70.70 148.788
51 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 43435074      72.09 150.178
52 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 43435084      70.93 149.018
53 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 43435086      72.14 150.228
54 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 44425470      72.05 150.138
55 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 44425476      72.05 150.138
56 1980-01-08 Torgau 78.088 45426142      75.91 153.998
```

---

**Edit to write the data to files**

I gues the writing can be done simpler like so:

```
write.mkz  = function(df, workspace) {
  write.csv(df,paste0(workspace,'/',unique(df$MKZ),".csv"), row.names = F)
  return(df)
}

workspace = ...
new.df %>% 
  group_by(MKZ) %>% 
  do(write.mkz(., workspace))
```

Comment: Thats one way to do it with first MKZ. Unfortunately I want to do it with all MKZ's of df1. Therefore I need an "automatic" solution to create timeseries for all MKZ of df1. The actual df1 is much longer than this example.

Comment: Then you can skip `df1 <- df1 %>% filter(MKZ == 43420072)` this filtering (see edit)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've modified the dataframe names a bit and added a Loop to create the timeseries in the end, which worked fine, exept for Pegel: Schöna. 

I dont know why only those timeseries are empty while the others work fine.

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is for Schona without seeing the whole dataset, but if these are empty they are probably not present in `df1` or you changed the names such that `df1` and `df2.new` now got more columns in common besides `Pegel`. If this is the case the `left_join` will join on all shared columns, to fix this you can fill in the `by` parameter in the join `new.df <- df2.new %>%  left_join(df1, by = "Pegel")`

Comment: Note that in your given datset  `Pegel ==  Schöna` does not exist in `df1` (i.e. `Werte`) therefore it's empty in the `new.df`

Comment: As far as I can see you write each MKZ to a new file, so you can do this without looping (see my edit)

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the Problem which was german spelling: Schöna <-> Schoena. I fixed it now and everythings works fine.